# Source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, null, syntax-error

So i had 676 line program, Now i have had a issue in the past when I opened the file all my code had disapeared so this time i made a backup. However when I try to copy and paste my backedup code then run it, it gives me this syntax error:

```
Source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

This was not displayed when I first made the backup and the program was working fine. I really do not want to go through 676 lines redoing it all. 
Im a pretty basic programmer when it comes to Python.

I already tried removing all white space and comments/# (Red background colour is at the end of a #)
Already looked through all the code and it really has no errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Maybe you copied a null byte somewhere there?

Comment: [Pastebin to code](https://pastebin.com/uegM0AL2)

Comment: I did a copy/paste on your code.  It runs fine under Python3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely just what the error message tells you: your back-up copy somehow got "infected" with one or more null bytes (ASCII value 00).  Paste your code one block at a time -- say, 50 lines -- to find which contain illegal bytes.  Delete the most recently-added code, maybe 5 lines at a time, to find which has the null byte.  Retype the offending line, and go on to the next.

Another possibility is to write a simple Python script that reads the file and removes the null bytes use the string `replace` method:

```
with open("homework.py", 'r') as infile:
    hw = infile.readlines().replace(chr(0), '')
```

Now close the file, open it again for 'w', and dump the `hw` variable to it.

Comment: Copied in sections going by subroutine and it worked fine, I programmed it in 3.6.2 and its always worked in that version till now. I guess every time it happens il just copy and paste it. Thanks for the help dude!